# Why is the order of modifier keys important in AHK?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey, modifier-keys

I'm using Autohotkey to perform a macro when Alt+Control+f is pressed within [Electron](https://www.electronjs.org/).

I have:

```
#SingleInstance

#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.

SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

#IfWinActive ^Electron
Alt::Return ;Disables the key alt when it's pressed alone

; Control & Alt & F to run macro
!^f::
{
; wait for release of keys
   KeyWait Control
   KeyWait Alt
   KeyWait f
; reproduce sequence
   SendInput ^f
   sleep 200
   SendInput fig{+}
   Return
}
#IfWinActive
```

However if I press Control then Alt it doesn't work and the menus appear like when I used to press Alt alone (even if I disabled Alt alone, see first line). When I press Alt+Control+f the macro works fine.

Why is that? I thought that the trigger "!^f" triggers when all three keys are in the pressed state, no matter how I got there.

How should I modify the macro to have it trigger no matter the order of Alt and Control?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works for me.
Which AutoHotKey version are you using? Mine is V1.

Perhaps this code will work better for you :

```
Alt::return

#If, GetKeyState("Alt", "P") and GetKeyState("Control", "P")
!^f::
  SendInput ^f
  sleep 200
  SendInput fig{+}
  return
```

Comment: Using your first two blocks to replace my Alt::Return interferes with my macro defined afterwards: it sends control+f correctly but it never gets to type the "fig+". But indeed you are right, in Electron control+alt+f and alt+control+f produce different results, while in other apps both work. I'm not sure why. I also closed all other AHK instances and left the scripts above, same result.

Comment: You're that the two produce different result, probably because that the first Alt key gets eaten up. In fact, my code (and yours) is no good since it destroys also all Alt+key combinations.

Comment: My new code seems to work better.

Comment: For info, I posted the whole script including headers. About Alt being eaten up: I have other Alt+number shortcuts defined both within Electron and in an AHK script (just now as test: "!l:: SendInput test") and they work without being eaten up.

Comment: Did you try my new code above ?

Comment: Your code with a simple MsgBox works both with alt-control-f and control-alt-f, thanks. But once I add the block I posted at the beginning, it goes back to the same behaviour.

Comment: Which block is that?

Comment: The one between curly brackets

Comment: You shouldn't need the `KeyWait` commands.

Comment: Even without it, same issue.

Comment: I added your code to my script, as above, and it works well for me.

Comment: Then it must be my system, it doesn't here.